# Typsescript not working in fresh Vue3 project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

After creating a new app using Vue CLI (Vue3, Babel, Typescript) the 'config' object on the main app object returned from the createApp function is not accessible.

I can see the Typescript '**App**' type, and the associated **config: AppConfig** type, by drilling down in VS Code.

But VS Code highlights access to 'config' as an error:

> Property 'config' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{},
> {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any,
> any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>>'.ts(2339)

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app') 

app.config <-- can't do this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is because the mount method returns the `ComponentPublicInstance` rather than the `vue` instance itself. Since you've chained it to `createApp` method, the `app` constant will not contain the `vue` instance. Naturally, not allowing access to the config property. See the function signature below:

```js
mount(rootContainer: HostElement | string, isHydrate?: boolean, isSVG?: boolean): ComponentPublicInstance;
```

You'll need to re-write the code as below in order to access the config property of the `vue` instance.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store);
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app');

// You'll be able to access the config now
app.config;
```